# The analysis of the token position results for the synonym in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES 7.11, and I have following simple code snippet:

```
PUT lib81
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "usa,united states,u s a,united states of america"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "description": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_synonyms"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I try to understand the analysis result with following code snippet:

```
GET /lib81/_analyze
{
  "field": "description",
  "text": "The United States is wealthy"
}
```

The result is as follows, each () has the same token position.

```
(the) 
(united uas u united)
(states s states) 
(is a of )
(wealthy america)
```

I would ask how the analysis works that leads the token position result as above.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When using multi-word synonyms, it's actually recommended to use the [`synonym_graph` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-graph-tokenfilter.html) instead of `synonym`. The reason is called [lossy serialization](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/04/lucenes-tokenstreams-are-actually.html).

Also worth noting is that `synonym_graph` is intended only for search time analyzers and not indexing time analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

The two words in the sentence "United" & "States" at position 1 and 2 are replaced with each synonym. The synonym requires it's own positions and overlaps position with the next token if the number of words in the synonym are more than the original word.

So, here is the position of each word in the actual sentence after application of synonym filter:

usa -> 1

united -> 1 states-> 2

u -> 1 s-> 2 a-> 3

united -> 1 states -> 2 of -> 3 america -> 4

These positions overlap with the existing positions of other tokens generated from the sentence,

the -> 0 united -> 1 states -> 2 is -> 3 wealthy -> 4

Hence, the tokens at the same position.